# Add more folder templates in windows explorer

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

Windows, since the old days, includes 5 folder templates that one can use to modify the UI. Plus, once a template is updated, all folders with that template get the same settings.
That would be awesome if we could add more template to apply to different kind of folders. Of course it can be override in a per-folder way, but this doesn't allow mass-updates.

Is there a way to add more than the original 5 folder templates in windows?

[image]